# How to find full path of Outlook .pst file?

Tags: winapi, vba, outlook, registry, pst

Is there a way to programmatically find the location of the current user's Outlook .pst file(s) through an API call or registry entry?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With [Outlook Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), you can iterate the message stores in VBA using `RDOStores`collection, accessible via the `RDOSession.Stores` property.

I am looking into the possibility of doing something similar in out-of-the-box VBA...

EDIT:

Obviously, the path to the PST is encoded in the StoreId string. Google turned up [this](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.office.developer.outlook.vba/topic42609.aspx):

```
Sub PstFiles()
  Dim f As MAPIFolder

  For Each f In Session.Folders
    Debug.Print f.StoreID
    Debug.Print GetPathFromStoreID(f.StoreID)
  Next f
End Sub

Public Function GetPathFromStoreID(sStoreID As String) As String
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim i As Long
  Dim lPos As Long
  Dim sRes As String

  For i = 1 To Len(sStoreID) Step 2
    sRes = sRes & Chr("&h" & Mid$(sStoreID, i, 2))
  Next

  sRes = Replace(sRes, Chr(0), vbNullString)
  lPos = InStr(sRes, ":\")

  If lPos Then
    GetPathFromStoreID = Right$(sRes, (Len(sRes)) - (lPos - 2))
  End If
End Function
```

Just tested, works as designed.

Comment: The convenience of Redemption is that it explicitly exposes RDOPstStore.PstPath property (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOPstStore) without having to hack the store entry id.

Answer (score 0):

The path should be somewhere under:

> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging
>   Subsystem\Profiles\Outlook]

Maybe this helps a bit.